# How can I edit Google Docs from Emacs?

Tags: google-docs

Is there a gdocs-mode or something I could use to edit Google Docs?

Comment: Can't you just sync your documents using google drive and edit them locally ? Emacs does not do well with proprietery file formats such as .doc or .ppt anyway.

Comment: This question is a little vague as is. Do you mean something for editing files on the cloud? Or do you want a major mode for .doc files?

Comment: @Malabarba No, I'm literally referring to google docs (e.g. interacting with their api).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emacs g-client is all that I've ever heard of, at one point it could edit google docs but last I've known it doesn't work any more, you can try it out yourself:

https://code.google.com/p/emacspeak/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Flisp%2Fg-client